# Twitter widgets not working on firefox private browser

Tags: jquery, html, twitter, plugins, widget

Good Day!

I'm having problem on twitter widget.js. When I browse on private browsing in firefox I get error "The resource at "http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" was blocked because tracking protection is enabled."

This is my implementation below.

Js:

```
window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.height=300;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);

  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
```

my html:`<a class="twitter-timeline" data-chrome = "noheader transparent" data-dnt="true" href="https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=testuser"></a>`

When I browse in normal browsing it works perfectly but not on private browser.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private browsers in default don't allow cookies or other tracking items to be saved. In order to sign into most secure websites, cookies are required. There's nothing wrong with your code, it is just that the point of a private browser is to block all resources that could get personal information.

Comment: Thanks for the response @sub6resources I thought I have missed something wrong. :)

Comment: Any solution for this?